# How do you render an image with Card.Img in React Bootstrap and Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I created a component that makes a Card with a photo and text inside the image, however, I get the alt text when rendering the <Card.Img> tag but  displays the image to the site. Should I just use src or is there a way to use fluid?

```
const Page = ({ title, subtitle, path, date, body, image}) => {
    return(
        <Card>
            <Card.Img fluid={image} alt="Card image" />
            <Card.ImgOverlay>
                <Card.Title> {title} </Card.Title>
                <Card.Subtitle> {subtitle} </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Subtitle> {path} </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Subtitle> {date} </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Body> {body} </Card.Body>
                <Img fluid={image} />
            </Card.ImgOverlay>
        </Card>

    )
}
export default Page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Card.Img` does not have a `fluid` prop by default, but the `Image` component does. Also, take note that `fluid` accepts a `boolean` value, not an image source. You can use the `as` prop of the `Card.Img` component to use a custom component `Image` if you must use the `fluid` properties.

```
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";

<Card.Img as={Image} src={image} fluid={true} alt="Card image" />
```

---

An alternate solution would be to just include the class of `img-fluid` to the `Card.Img`

```
<Card.Img src={image} className="img-fluid" alt="Card image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `<Img>` component from [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) your need to query the data using the `childImageSharp` GraphQL fragment or an alternative approach to fetch all the needed data. In your case, I assume that the `image` `prop` only contains the source of the image, not all the data from the query fragment itself that's why your image is not showing.

Without seeing your query, you have three workarounds:

- Use the native HTML `<img>` tag:

  ```
          <Card.ImgOverlay>
              <Card.Title> {title} </Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle> {subtitle} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Subtitle> {path} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Subtitle> {date} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Body> {body} </Card.Body>
              <img src={image} alt={`Your alt text`}/>
          </Card.ImgOverlay>
  ```
- Use the `<Card.Img>` component from React Boostrap:

  ```
          <Card.ImgOverlay>
              <Card.Title> {title} </Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle> {subtitle} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Subtitle> {path} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Subtitle> {date} </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Body> {body} </Card.Body>
              <Card.Img src={image} alt={`Your alt text`}/>
          </Card.ImgOverlay>
  ```
- Use the GraphQL query fragment to retrieve all the needed data to use `gatsby-image` properly. An ideal approach should look like:

  ```
  import React from "react"
  import { graphql } from "gatsby"
  import Img from "gatsby-image"

  export default ({ data }) => (
     <div>
       <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
       <Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />
     </div>
  )

  export const query = graphql`
     query {
       file(relativePath: { eq: "your/path/to/image.jpeg" }) {
         childImageSharp {
           # Specify the image processing specifications right in the query.
           # Makes it trivial to update as your page's design changes.
           fluid(width: 125) {
             ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
           }
         }
       }
     }
  `
  ```

  *Note that you may need to adapt the snippet above to your component, specifications, and requirements.*

  As you can see, the GraphQL query above contains the `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` fragment (that is exactly the same to get one by one all the properties from the image). Now, your `data` object contains all the data needed to use the `<Img>` component and you can use the `fluid` `prop` with `<Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />`

  You can check for further details in the [Gatsby Image documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#how-to-use)